# I am learning Paypal implemention on my webpage which is offline

Tags: paypal, resolve, demo

I got the below mention error:

```
Error : Security header is not valid

Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d10%2d11T05%3a34%3a56Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => aa9e086c3a330
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 13298800
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

How can I resolve this? I have try a lot but I didn't understand what to do next so is there any one who can suggest me what to do regarding above mention error.

Best Regards,
J!mmy~

Comment: possible duplicate of [PayPal gateway has rejected request. Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely due to the incorrect API signature or API endpoint.
Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur/23265150#23265150) and validate your integration.

Comment: Cool, hope you figured the issue!