# Paypal API error paypal.exceptions.PayPalAPIResponseError: u'Security header is not valid' (Error Code: 10002)

Tags: python, api, paypal

I'm trying to use the Paypal classic api with python but I keep getting the 10002 error. I understand this is to do with authentication, so I have checked all of the authentication details, but all seems fine.

Here is the code:

```
from paypal import PayPalInterface

paypal_api = PayPalInterface(API_USERNAME="xxxxx",\
API_PASSWORD="xxxxx",\
API_SIGNATURE="xxxxx",\
DEBUG_LEVEL=0,\
HTTP_TIMEOUT=30)

balance = paypal_api._call('GetBalance')
```

Here I try to get the account balance, but get the error code:

> paypal.exceptions.PayPalAPIResponseError: u'Security header is not
>   valid' (Error Code: 10002)

I also get the same error code using the TransactionSearch method. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur/23265150#23265150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to access with **live** PayPal credentials (not sandbox), you can set:

```
API_ENVIRONMENT = "PRODUCTION"
```