# Getting started with PayPal Express Checkout Classic API

Tags: api, paypal, express-checkout

Note I am using Classic API because I am in a country where I can't use the REST API for credit card payments.

I am just getting started on setting up an application to use Express Checkout instead of Payment Standard and I'm totally lost with PayPal's API set-up. They made it incredibly difficult even reading the documentation.

I did the following already:

- Set up a Classic API account for my "App" and got:

  `Sandbox ID: APP-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Live App ID: APP-XXXXXXXXXXXXX`
- Generated API Signature in my Premier account and got:

  `Credential: API Signature
  API Username    : name_api1.domain.com
  API Password: XXXXXXXXXXXX
  Signature: (Really long string)`

Now, I figured out that I can call this to create a test token like this:

```
curl -s --insecure  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
-d  "USER=platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com&
PWD=1255077037&
SIGNATURE=Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf&
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
VERSION=78&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&
cancelUrl=http://www.example.com/cancel.html&
returnUrl=http://www.example.com/success.html
```

But how do I call it with my own API username and password? I tried replacing my info with the `PWD` and the `USER` and it's not working.

Do I always test with the above cURL request while in sandbox? Or should I be using my own? If so, how? And what is the Sandbox ID for? I can't seem to specify it anywhere in the cURL.

I checked the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec but it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a lot of documentation, yes, but what exactly doesn't make sense about it?  Are you starting with the Get Started material, reading all the way through it, and then proceeding to the more detailed docs about the API calls, or are you skipping some of that?

Express Checkout does not require the App ID, so you don't need to worry about that.  That would be for if you ever need to use the Adaptive Payments APIs in the future.

You say the sample they provide is working, but then you try your own credentials and "it's not working."  That is not nearly enough information for anybody to help you with.  Do you get an error code?  Is it the security header invalid error, by chance, or what is it?

Are you working with PHP by chance?  If so, check out [this library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It'll make everything much easier for you.

Get me some of the details and then I'll update this answer (with an actual answer).  This was all too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! :) That library is indeed very helpful. I think I'll go with that. And yes, the error is `LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid`. What is causing that? I made sure that the username, password and signature are correct.

Comment: Or is it possible that it's because I am using LIVE credentials on the sandbox account?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur/23265150#23265150

Comment: I'll be damned. My credentials work on the LIVE but not on the SANDBOX. Do I have to generate a different set of credentials for the sandbox?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create separate credentials for sandbox accounts and be sure to use the correct credentials with the correct endpoints (sandbox vs. live)