# Magento - PayPal payment pro - 10002 security header is not valid error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal payment pro into my Magento website.

Whenever I try a test transaction it gives me the following error:

> "10002 (security header is not valid error)"

```
2015-04-23T11:51:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [DoDirectPayment] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
            [IPADDRESS] => 119.157.225.205
            [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
            [AMT] => 385.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [INVNUM] => 100000055
            [NOTIFYURL] => http://202.142.XXX.XX/apex-gb/index.php/paypal/ipn/
            [EMAIL] => ksaleem@folio3.com
            [CREDITCARDTYPE] => ****
            [ACCT] => ****
            [EXPDATE] => ****
            [CVV2] => ****
            [ISSUENUMBER] => 
            [ITEMAMT] => 385.00
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [L_NUMBER0] => 03april-ARC818105ET27HS-ARC818105ET27HS
            [L_NAME0] => 18" ARC-8 Group Buy - 03 Apr 4:37
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 400.00
            [L_NUMBER1] => 
            [L_NAME1] => Discount
            [L_QTY1] => 1
            [L_AMT1] => -15.00
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [FIRSTNAME] => Kashif
            [LASTNAME] => Saleem
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [STATE] => CA
            [CITY] => Beverly Hills
            [STREET] => 123123
            [ZIP] => 90210
            [PHONENUM] => 12312312312312
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
            [SHIPTOCITY] => Beverly Hills
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => 123123
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 90210
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 12312312312312
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => Kashif Saleem
            [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-04-23T11:48:34Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => fe7639e2a70d1
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 16204765
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 29903
```

Can anybody help me, Thanx in advance

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23265150/2568469

Comment: Tried contacting PayPal pro.. while integrating payment gateways they guide the developer's in all possible way. You should contact them.

Comment: Make sure that your paypal account  in TEST mode, and your API data for TEST mode.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure username/password/signature is correct.

Some possible errors:
* space at end or beginning
* "I" or "l" (better copy the long string directly)